# NAudio playback won't stop successfully

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

When using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) to playback an [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) file [in the console], I can't figure out how to stop the playback. When I call waveout.Stop() the code just stops running and waveout.Dispose() never gets called.

Has it something to do with the function callback? If it is, how do I fix it?

```
static string MP3 = @"song.mp3";
static WaveOut waveout;
static WaveStream playback;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    waveout = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
    playback = OpenMp3Stream(MP3);
    waveout.Init(playback);
    waveout.Play();
    Console.WriteLine("Started");

    Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000);

    Console.WriteLine("Ending");
    if (waveout.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
        waveout.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
    waveout.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("1st dispose");
    playback.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("2nd dispose");
}
private static WaveChannel32 OpenMp3Stream(string fileName)
{
    WaveChannel32 inputStream;
    WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
    WaveStream pcmStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3Reader);
    WaveStream blockAlignedStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(pcmStream);
    inputStream = new WaveChannel32(blockAlignedStream);
    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling the `using` statement would be very handy here but I don't have naudio so I can't really test it out.

Comment: well this is only sample code, I dont think using a using statement would really work in the long run. Its not actually returning from the call waveout.Stop() at all. It enters the function and doesnt seem to leave at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying the code hangs in the call to waveOutReset? If so, this is a known issue with function callbacks and certain audio drivers (SoundMAX seems particularly susceptible to this). I checked in a possible fix to the NAudio source code a couple of months ago, so you could try building the latest code and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I stumbled onto this. I had the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess here is that since you have no console.read() or similar call that your code is just executing so fast that you don't see the final write lines.

If NAudio implements IDisposable then i would recommend using a using statement to have .NET handle this for you.